# How Can I migrate ami with root volume and attached encrypted ebs volume from one amazon account to another

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, cloud, devops

I have AMI with root volume and encrypted ebs volume attached. I want to migrate both to another aws account. How can I migrate both root and encrypted ebs to another account. How to use KMS encryption keys.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate your instance to another aws account you have to create an AMI out of it and then you can copy that AMI to other AWS account of yours.

An AMI includes the following:

A template for the root volume for the instance (for example, an operating system, an application server, and applications)
Launch permissions that control which AWS accounts can use the AMI to launch instances.

A block device mapping that specifies the volumes to attach to the instance when it's launched

During the AMI-creation process, Amazon EC2 creates snapshots of your instance's root volume and any other EBS volumes attached to your instance. If any volumes attached to the instance are encrypted, the new AMI only launches successfully on instances that support Amazon EBS encryption.

To migrate an ec2 instance first create a AMI of it you can follow the steps mentioned in the [AWS Documentation or Creating AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html#creating-an-ami).

To copy your AMI to a different AWS account follow this [AWS Document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html).

**Note:** You do not need to share the Amazon EBS snapshots that an AMI references in order to share the AMI. Only the AMI itself needs to be shared; the system automatically provides the instance access to the referenced Amazon EBS snapshots for the launch.

Comment: You are missing the `encrypted EBS` part in the question.